# How to extract images from gif using giflib to cv::Mat in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, gif

I'm trying to extract images from gif using giflib in order to bind them in Opencv Mat.
I'm currently using Opencv-2.4.5 and giflib-4.1.6-10.

My problem is that I can extract only extract the first image of the gif.
The second and the others are scratched, I think it is a matter of bits alignement.

Following the doc: http://giflib.sourceforge.net/gif_lib.html

```
SavedImage *SavedImages; /* Image sequence (high-level API) */
```

Should provide a pointer to bits of images.

```
#include <gif_lib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


int main(int ac, char **av){
    int *err;
    GifFileType *f = DGifOpenFileName(av[1]);
    assert(f != NULL);
    int ret = DGifSlurp(f);
    assert(ret == GIF_OK);
    int width = f->SWidth;
    int height = f->SHeight;
    cout << f->ImageCount << endl;
    cout << width << " : " <<  height<< endl;
    cout << f->SColorResolution << endl;

    // SavedImage *image = &f->SavedImages[0]; Does actually works
    SavedImage *image = &f->SavedImages[1]; // that compile but the result is a scratched img


    Mat  img = Mat(Size(width, height), CV_8UC1, image->RasterBits);
    imwrite("test.png", img);

    DGifCloseFile(f);
    return 0;
}
```

I don't want to use ImageMagick to keep a little piece of code and keep it "light".

Thanks for your Help.

Answer (score 2):

Did you check whether your GIF file is interlaced ? If it is , you should consider it before storing rasterbits into a bitmap format.
Also check the top,left,width and height of the "SavedImages" , every frame does not need to cover all canvas so you should only overwrite pixels that are different from the last frame.